# Ruby get a list of all matching strings between two words using regex

Tags: ruby, regex, match

I can't figure out how to get a list of all matching strings between two words using regex. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
string='some text "MediaUrl":"link1" some more text "MediaUrl":"link2" more text "MediaUrl":"link3" more text'
```

I'd like to extract link1, link2, and link3 from the string above.

I've tried:

```
string[/MediaUrl\":\"(.+?)\"/m][1]
```

the problem there is it only returns the first result (link1) but I'd like to return an array of all links found between matching regex. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string.scan(/MediaUrl":"(.+?)"/)`

Comment: Double quotes don't have to be escaped by the way, so you can clean it up slightly to become `/MediaUrl":"(.+?)"/`